# How to authenticate user, using PassportJS using local strategy during user registration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I'm following a Udemy Course and in that there is this section where the tutor saves the user to mongoDB, using passport-local-mongoose, and after saving there is an Authenticate function which it doesn't support the call back function that was used by the tutor(In my latest version of NodeJS).

I tried reading the docs and implement but it didn't work for me, where the the authenticate function doesn't get executed.

Tutor's code,

```
app.post("/register", function (req, res) {
  User.register({ username: req.body.username }, req.body.password, function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect("/register");
      } else {
        console.log("Check user Registeration success");
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function () {
          console.log("User is now Authenticated");
          res.redirect("/secrets");
        });
      }
    }
  );
});
```

The above code doesn't work in mine, I get an error saying call back function not supported.

My code,

```
app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  User.register({ username: req.body.username }, req.body.password)
    .then((user) => {
      console.log("Check user Registeration success");
      passport.authenticate("local"),
        (req, res) => {
          console.log("User is now Authenticated");
          res.redirect("/secrets");
        };
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

In my code, the code gets executed up to the part where the user gets registered and "Check user Registration success" gets prints in the console log. But the line passport.authenticate doesn't get executed, so the "User is now Authenticated" is not printed in the console log.

How do I properly use the passport.Authenticate function with the "local" strategy, by using the latest version of passport-local-mongoose ?

Here is my entire code,

```
import "dotenv/config";
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import session from "express-session";
import passport from "passport";
import passportLocalMongoose from "passport-local-mongoose";

const saltRounds = 10;
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "Our little secret.",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB", { useNewUrlParser: true });

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser);

passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("home.ejs");
});

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.render("login.ejs");
});

app.get("/register", (req, res) => {
  res.render("register.ejs");
});

app.get("/secrets", (req, res) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    console.log("Trying rendering secrets ejs");
    res.render("secrets.ejs");
  } else {
    console.log("Failed rendering secrets ejs");
    res.redirect("/login");
  }
});


app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  User.register({ username: req.body.username }, req.body.password)
    .then((user) => {
      console.log("Check user Registeration success");
      passport.authenticate("local"),
        (req, res) => {
          console.log("User is now Authenticated");
          res.redirect("/secrets");
        };
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
});

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: I am missing the rest of your code!

Comment: Just now updated it

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling `passport.authenticate` correctly. You should pass `(req, res, callback)` as the arguments.

**Wrong:**
It's not calling passport.authenticate with (req, res, callback).

```
passport.authenticate("local"),
(req, res) => {
  console.log("User is now Authenticated");
  res.redirect("/secrets");
};
```

**Right:**
`passport.authenticate("local")` is followed by `(req, res, callback)`.

```
passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, () => {
  console.log("User is now Authenticated");
  res.redirect("/secrets");
});
```